# Homology and Neighborhood

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $X$ a connected manifold, $x \in X$ and $V$ a neighborhood of $x$. Assume $i:V \to X$ induce isomorphism between all homology groups.

> Does $X-p$ and $V-p$ still have the same homology groups ?

Motivation : I think this is true if $X,V$ have no homology. The first case when it's false is where $X$ is the sphere $\mathbb S^2$ and $V$ a small ball intersected with $X$, containing $p$. We have $H_1(X-p) = 0$ when $H_1(V-p) \cong \mathbb Z$. But here $H_2(X)$ is not isomorphic to $H_2(V)$
 ! So my guess is the first condition is strong enough for give me this isomorphism.

Comment: By «$X$ and $V$ have the same homology groups» what do you mean, exacty? That the inclusion $V\to X$ induces an isomorphism in homology? If so, it is always better to be explicit. Also, a space cannot «have no homology»: at most, i can have zero homology.

Comment: I don't know, because it's only a question I asked to myself (it's not from a book). I was just thinking "pointwise" isomorphism $H_k(X) \cong H_k(V)$ should be enough. For "have no homology" I meant $H_k(X) = \{0\}$ for all $k \geq 1$.

Comment: why should that be enough?

Comment: As I said, I have no ideas... It's just pure speculation. I just tried to think to a counter-example and I didn't find any. That's why I asked my question here !

Comment: «Having the same homology groups» is almost never a good hypothesis to do anything, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the inclusion $V\to X$ induces isomorphisms in homology. Consider now the inclusion of pairs $(V,V\setminus\{p\})\to(X,X\setminus\{p\})$, fromwhich you can construct a big diagram: the two rows are the the long exact sequences of the pairs $(V,V\setminus\{p\})$ and $(X,X\setminus\{p\})$ and the maps going from the groups in one to the coresponding groups in the other are induced by inclusions.

The hypothesis is that the maps $H_*(V)\to H_*(X)$ are isomorphisms. If you can prove that the maps $H_*(V,V\setminus\{p\})\to H_*(X,X\setminus\{p\})$ are also isomorphism, the $5$-lemma will tell you that the maps $H_*(V\setminus\{p\})\to H_*(X\setminus\{p\})$ are also isomorphisms, which gives you want you want. Can you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will try to think about it and I will come back with a solution (I hope :) )

Comment: Wait, I think it's just a consequence of the excision theorem right ?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to add the details of what you have in mind — «just a consequence of excision» can mean quite a few things.

Comment: Excision theorem says : if $U \subset cl(U) \subset A \subset X$ then $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(X \backslash U, A \backslash U)$. So here, we're done with $X=X,A=X-p$ and $U = V^c$. Of course $V^c \subset X -p$ and even the closure because it's a closed subset.

Comment: I edited my question and added your better hypothesis. Thanks for helping me.